# YouTube iFrame API captions displaySettings does not change fontStyle

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

For a valid YouTube video with captions, the following options are returned.

```
  player.getOption("captions", "displaySettings");
  {
    background:"#080808",
    backgroundOpacity:0.75,
    charEdgeStyle:"none",
    color:"#fff",
    fontFamily:4,
    fontFamilyOption:"propSans",
    fontSizeIncrement:0,
    textOpacity:1,
    windowColor:"#080808",
    windowOpacity:0
  }
```

Attempting to change any of the above properties as shown below doesn’t result in any changes to the caption style.

```
  YTPlayer.setOption("captions", "displaySettings", {fontFamily: 2});
```

Is the API broken or is there a missing step?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the options for [setOption in the iFrameAPI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events), you can see that there's no fontStyle option, only fontSize

[image]

If you're using [this blog](http://terrillthompson.com/blog/648) as reference, note that this post was written in 2015 and it's for HTML5 player. The writer also warned:

> "I'm not sure whether that means the API Reference is out of date or
>   the undocumented options are unofficial and might disappear without
>   notice. Since the latter might be a possibility, you should exercise
>   caution in using these options."

So, just follow the official documentation.